# Is there a name for this "Collatz constant"?

Tags: prime-numbers, constants, collatz-conjecture

Right now I'm calling a convergent number based on the Collatz conjecture the "Collatz constant". I'm wondering if it have an *actual* name? And if it actually converges?

**Details**

The Collatz conjecture provides an algorithm, namely, starting at any positive integer $i$ greater than 1, if $i\equiv 0 \pmod2$ then take $\frac{i}{2}$; otherwise take $3i+1$ and continue.

That gives us a sequence of numbers (assuming the sequence always comes back to $1$). So for $10$ we have $10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1$.

Consider adding one to each element in that sequence (ignoring the last element, 1) and taking their values $\pmod{2}$. That gives us $11, 6, 17, 9, 5, 3$ all $mod$ 2 which is $1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1$.

Now interpret this as a binary number, least significant digit first. In which case $101111_2$ is $61$ ($111101$ in traditional nomenclature).

I call $61$ the Collatz number of $10$. Let's call the Collatz number function $C$.

Now consider the sequence $C(i+1)-C(i)$ for $i$ from 1 to $n$.

I maintain the ratio of primes (specifically elements whose absolute values are prime) to non-primes in that sequence converges to a real number as $n \rightarrow\infty$, what I'm calling the Collatz constant.

For $n = 10, 100, 1000, 10,\!000, 100,\!000$, and $1,\!000,\!000$ the approximation of the Collatz constant is:

```
10:        0.25
100:       0.515152
1,000:     0.466276
10,000:    0.462202
100,000:   0.461305
1,000,000: 0.45999
```

---

(I have a conjecture of my own about Collatz numbers. You can see it [here](http://linkless.org/posts/collatz-primes/). Drop me a PM if you find it interesting.)

I've been having trouble posting questions that are clear to readers, so I hope this is better.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the ratio of primes to non-primes in the sequence'?

Comment: @extremeaxe5, take the first $n$ elements of the sequence. Let x be the number of primes, and y be the number of non-primes. The ratio is $x/y$.

Comment: You basically just found the "parity vector" of that collatz sequence. Reversed parity vector or not. So it has a name: "parity vector". Wether or not it converges I have no idea. I think its similar or related to the same as asking wether the Collatz sequence converges for all numbers?

Comment: Seems like a cool idea :)

Comment: @goblin Thanks :-) I'll be pretty happy if it does in fact converge. Fingers crossed.

Comment: If you read on Wikipedia it's standard to consider the parity sequence given by $1$ if the number's odd and $0$ if the number's even. It looks like your Collatz number is the same as that except exchanging $0$s for $1$s and vice versa.

Comment: It's basically the parity vector inversed: $P^{-1}(x)$ in binary or something.

Comment: To define this sequence, you need to assume the Collatz conjecture is true.